# table of figures failing to break only one caption line out of dozens of caption lines

Tags: table-of-contents, captions, line-breaking, tocloft

I have a list of figures that breaks dozens of figure caption lines according to the margin settings, except for this one line of this one figure caption. If I add a word to the figure caption the line is correctly broken and the problem is solved, so it seems the length of the text in that particular figure caption is like "borderline" with respect to my overall margin settings. Are there any other methods available to break that single caption line without having to add a word or change the margin settings?

Here the required MWE:

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt,oneside,english,singlespacing,headsepline]{MastersDoctoralThesis} % The class file specifying the document structure

\usepackage[cp1252]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage[none]{hyphenat} % Hyphenation control

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{float}

%------------------------------------------------------------------
%   MARGIN SETTINGS
%------------------------------------------------------------------
\geometry{
    paper=a4paper, % Change to letterpaper for US letter
    inner=2.5cm, % Inner margin (original: 2.5cm)
    outer=3.8cm, % Outer margin (original: 3.8cm)
    bindingoffset=.5cm, % Binding offset
    top=2.0cm, % Top margin (original: 1.5cm)
    bottom=1.0cm, % Bottom margin (original: 1.5cm)
    %showframe, % Uncomment to show how the type block is set on the page
}

\usepackage{tocloft} % manipulation of lists of contents, figures, and tables

% larger indentation for lists of contents, figures, and tables
\renewcommand{\cftchapindent}{0 em}
\renewcommand{\cftchapnumwidth}{1.5 em}

\renewcommand{\cftsecindent}{1.5 em}
\renewcommand{\cftsecnumwidth}{2.3 em}
 
\renewcommand{\cftsubsecindent}{3.8 em}
\renewcommand{\cftsubsecnumwidth}{3.2 em}

\renewcommand{\cftsubsubsecindent}{7.0 em}
\renewcommand{\cftsubsubsecnumwidth}{4.1 em}

\renewcommand{\cftfigindent}{1.5 em}
\renewcommand{\cftfignumwidth}{3.2 em} %3.2em instead of original 2.3em

\renewcommand{\cfttabindent}{1.5 em}
\renewcommand{\cfttabnumwidth}{3.2 em} %3.2em instead of original 2.3em

%---------------------------------------------------------------------
% THESIS INFORMATION
%---------------------------------------------------------------------

\thesistitle{Thesis Title} % Your thesis title, this is used in the title and abstract, print it elsewhere with \ttitle
\author{John \textsc{Smith}} % Your name, this is used in the title page and abstract, print it elsewhere with \authorname
\keywords{} % Keywords for your thesis, this is not currently used anywhere in the template, print it elsewhere with \keywordnames

%-------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   HYPERLINKS, BOOKMARKS, ETC.
%-------------------------------------------------------------------------

\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\AtBeginDocument{
\hypersetup{pdftitle=\ttitle} % Set the PDF's title to your title
\hypersetup{pdfauthor=\authorname} % Set the PDF's author to your name
\hypersetup{pdfkeywords=\keywordnames} % Set the PDF's keywords to your keywords
\hypersetup{allcolors=blue,colorlinks=true,linktocpage,bookmarksopen,bookmarksnumbered} % SOFTCOVER/ SOFTCOPY (all hyperlinks in blue)
}

\usepackage{bookmark}

\begin{document}

\sloppy

\pdfbookmark[0]{TITLE}{title}

\frontmatter % Use roman page numbering style (i, ii, iii, iv...) for the pre-content pages

\pagestyle{thesis} % Default to the plain heading style until the thesis style is called for the body content

\begin{titlepage}
\centerline{\Large{\textsc{Doctoral dissertation}}}
\noindent
\begin{center}
\large \textbf{TITLE}
\end{center}
\vspace*{0.1cm}\par
\noindent
\end{titlepage}

\cleardoublepage % for alternating margins
\pagenumbering{roman} % for unnumbered title and first blank page

\setstretch{1.25} % Line spacing of 1.25

%---------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   LIST OF CONTENTS/FIGURES/TABLES PAGES
%---------------------------------------------------------------------------

%\phantomsection
\pdfbookmark[0]{\contentsname}{toc}
\tableofcontents % Prints the main table of contents
%\clearpage % Start a new page
\cleardoublepage % for alternating margins

%\phantomsection
\pdfbookmark[0]{List of Figures}{lof}
%\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{List of Figures}
\listoffigures % Prints the list of figures
%\clearpage % Start a new page
\cleardoublepage % for alternating margins

%\phantomsection
\pdfbookmark[0]{List of Tables}{lot}
%\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{List of Tables}
\listoftables % Prints the list of tables
%\clearpage % Start a new page
%\cleardoublepage % for alternating margins


\mainmatter % Begin numeric (1,2,3...) page numbering

\begin{figure}[H] %[htbp] %[H]
\centering
\caption{This is an example of a figure caption that behaves normally with regard to the left and right margins, line breaks, etc.\label{fig:1}}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[H] %[htbp]
\centering
\caption{This is another example of a figure caption that behaves normally with regard to the left and right margins, line breaks, etc.\label{fig:2}}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[H] %[htbp]
\centering
\caption{This is yet another example of a figure caption that behaves normally with regard to the left and right margins, line breaks, etc.\label{fig:3}}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[H] %[htbp]
\centering
\caption{This is an example of a figure caption that misbehaves so to say with regard to the left and right margins, line breaks, etc., unlike all others\label{fig:2}}
\end{figure}



\fussy

\end{document}
```

Comment: Please edit your posting to provide more information about the document class that's in use, any LaTeX packages that may affect the appearance of captions, and any packages that may affect the appearance of the Table of Contents and the List of Figures. Which font and font size are in use? Last but not least, do please post the caption in question and (re)state the issue you wish to solve. In short, please provide a [minimum working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/5001) to enable readers to come up with a diagnosis and, in short order, a cure.

Comment: In addition, please clarify the meaning of "[line-]breaks dozens of figure caption lines according to the margin settings, except for this one line of this one figure caption". Specifically, what's the issue with this line: is it overfull or underfull? Something else?

Comment: **@Mico**: thanks for the help. I am using the document class `MastersDoctoralThesis` and I use both the caption and subcaption packages. Usually I post a MWE with my questions, but it's a bit difficut to do that for this particular case without providing sensitive information. I will try though.......

Comment: **@Mico**: the line in question goes a bit outside the right margin that is set for the caption text in the list of figures. The only change I did to the list of figures and tables was to increase spacing between figure and table numbers, as their numbering goes to three digits and I had the numbers overlapping with the caption text.......

Comment: **@Mico**: OK. Meanwhile, I was able to almost completely prepare a MWE reproducing the problem in question. I will post it latest in about an hour or so.......

Comment: **@Mico**: I just added the MWE....... it probably has to do with the definition of those dots before the page number in the list of figures. Probably the definition includes a space after the last dot, and that is why the word others in the last line of figure 2 caption does not start in a new line followed by dots. Is there a way of having these captions, including those dots, perfectly justified?

Comment: Is the file `MastersDoctoralThesis.cls` available online somewhere?

Comment: **@Mico**: sure. Here: [link](https://www.latextemplates.com/template/masters-doctoral-thesis)

Comment: **@Mico**: I added two more figures to make the problem even more clear. Essentially, the problem is that for the first three figures I always have a dot and the space right after it as the right hand side limit of the caption, but with the last caption that limit becomes the word others. Ideally, I always have a dot and the space right after it as the as the right hand side limit of all captions in the list of figures; all without changing my current margin and indentation settings or the text in the captions.......

Comment: I would really question some of your `tocloft`-related settings. In particular, setting `\renewcommand{\cftfigindent}{1.5 em}` (and `\renewcommand{\cfttabindent}{1.5 em}` too) seems rather suboptimal. Do check if changing this to `\renewcommand{\cftfigindent}{0em}` (and `\renewcommand{\cfttabindent}{0em}` and recompilling twice either eliminates the line overflow issues in the LoF, if it does not, or if new formatting issues arise in the LoF. Do also see if adding the instruction `\renewcommand{\cftfigfont}{\sloppy}` helps.

Comment: the reason for those indentation settings is obvious. List of Figures and List of Tables are aligned with the Contents indentation. Then, I treat the figure and table numbering as sections in a hypothetical "figure chapter" (that does not appear explicitly), similarly to the structure of the Table of Contents. I will try first the `\renewcommand{\cftfigfont}{\sloppy}`, before any indentation changes and get back to you!

Comment: **@Mico**: OK. The solution is to use `\cftsetpnumwidth{Xem}` with X = to some real number. That controls the distance between the dots and the page numbers, I just need to calculate the exact distance between the right margin of the text in my captions and the left margin of respective page numbers.......

Comment: The structure of the List of Figures are List of Tables lists is *flat*, quite unlike the structure of the Table of Contents list. If you think that your readers will appreciate your effort to "treat the figure and table numbering as sections", you may be bitterly disappointed in their utter indifference. In my view, the indentation of the one and only list level in the LoF and LoT should be equal to that of the indentation of the top-level entries in the ToC (chapters), i.e., `0em`.

Comment: **@Mico**: I should note that in the original settings of this thesis template, the figure and table numbers in the LoF and LoT, respectively, have a 1.5 indentation with respect to the left document margin. The only thing I changed was the figure and table number width to accomodate larger numbers and widths. I also should say that even if I set the left indentation to zero as you suggest, I might still have some captions with inappropriate line breaks, It completely depends on the specific caption text. Still, I''ll take all your input into consideration. Thanks a lot!

Comment: **@Mico**: see also Table 1, page 4 in here [link](http://mirrors.ibiblio.org/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/tocloft/tocloft.pdf) for seemingly standard indentations and widths.......

Comment: BTW, I just noticed a mistake in one of my earlier comments (which is also present in the code of your MWE): It's got to be `\setlength{\cftfigindent}{1.5 em}` (or whatever length you end up choosing), *not* `\renewcommand{\cftfigindent}{1.5 em}`.